# AWS Lambda doesn't read from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which fully works when tested locally using ATOM, within this it reads and writes to my s3 bucket. However when I upload the function to Lambda it doesn't seem to have access to S3. Whenever I try to read from S3 it simply times out after 3 minutes, even on simple requests like listing buckets.

I have increased the access of "Lambda Basic Execution" to have full admin access, and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your S3 Bucket policy.

Comment: There's not much information there to go on. How does the Lambda talk to S3 http or SDK calls? Can you provide more information, like a code snippet, configuration of your bucket, how you are deploying the Lambda, etc.

Comment: Is the Lambda running in VPC?

Comment: Did you specify all required variables in Environment variables (aws concole -> lambda service->pick a function->configuration> Environment variables)?

Answer (score 0):

According to information provided you have troubles with communication between deployed to server `lambda` and `S3`. When running on the local machine, where you have direct access to `S3`, there is no problem, because it is not isolated environment as in `VPC`.

Please check your network configuration (especially when `lambda` runs in `VPC`, for tests purposes you can disable that in `AWS console` -> `Lambda` -> `yourLambdaFunction` -> `Network` -> `choose No VPC`). Image below shows the `lambda` config for those tests:
[Lambda console no VPC config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkcjH.jpg)

It was mentioned before. Answers included should solve your problem:

[Lambda Timeout while communicating with S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963909/lambda-timeout-while-communicating-with-s3)

Please let us know if it helps.