# I can't download file from S3 to EFS using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-efs

I connected the Lambda to EFS, and I want to download small file from S3 to the EFS using Lambda.

I connected the Lambda function to file system, and added access point with permissions 777.

I have this small python function in Lambda to download to the mount:

```
import json
import boto3
import time
import os

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3.download_file('my_bucket', 'img.jpg', '/mnt/my-efs/img.jpg')
    return{
        "statusCode": 200
    }
```

And I get timeout after 1 min (this should take less than a second).

If I download for `/tmp/img.jpg`, this works. Even if I copy the file from `/tmp/` to `/mnt/my-efs/` this works.

I have this IAM for the Lambda user:

```
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AmazonVPCFullAccess
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
AmazonElasticFileSysstemClientReadWriteAccess
AmazonElasticFileSysstemClientFullAccess
```

**Why can't I download file from S3 to EFS using Lambda?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423246/adding-aws-lambda-with-vpc-configuration-causes-timeout-when-accessing-s3

Comment: @MarkB I'm not so sure it is. That question was about timing out when accessing S3 specifically, and OP said here that if they download to `/tmp/`, it works. So accessing S3 isn't the problem, it's writing to EFS.

Comment: Could you try writing to EFS directly, without downloading from S3? I think it would be helpful to narrow down the problem that way.

Comment: @brads3290 yes, i can create files directly to the EFS

Comment: I have same issue, and same goal, any answer would be appreciated! 

Comment: @TobiahRex did you find a solution ?

Comment: @asmdashdkj did you find a solution please ? I have exactly the same issue

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Oh yeah! I'll post an answer

Answer (score 9):

This get's a big tricky so let's go slow and make sure we cover all the moving parts. I apologize if some of this is redundant, but I wanted to make sure a layman would have all the right parts. Please let me know if you think I've missed something.

**Steps:**

1. `serverless.yaml`
2. AWS Access point settings
3. Adding EFS access to the Lambda
4. Downloading items into the EFS drive
5. Verifying your files are in EFS

**1. `serverless.yaml`**
I'm using *serverless* so this is what my `serverless.yaml` file looks like.

```yaml
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - elasticfilesystem:ClientMount
          - elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite
          - elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess
          Resource:
          - arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:123456789:file-system/fs-123456789
```

These were the minimum permissions i needed to download the file from S3 into the EFS drive location. Again, this project uses *serverless* so all this can be translated to a cloudFormation template if you're not using *serverless*.

And under the handler function...

```yaml
functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: handler.handle
    package:
      exclude:
        - env/**
        - node_modules/**
    description: Lambda to download S3 file to SFTP EFS folder.
    events:
        - s3:
          bucket: some-bucket
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: some-folder/
            - suffix: .jpg
          existing: true
    fileSystemConfig:
      localMountPath: /mnt/my-efs
      arn: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:123456789:access-point/fsap-12345678910
```

NOTE: I left out a lot from my `serverless.yaml` file, and only included the parts pertaining to the EFS setup.

**2. AWS EFS Access Point Settings**

- 1. go to EFS service.
- 2. click Access points.
- 3. Create new Access point
- 4. Fill out the fields as needed. Below is how i configured mine

  - **Details**

    - `File System:` Choose a dropdown selection
    - `Name - optional` Pick a name
    - `Root directory path - optional:` This will map to your underlying file system on the EC2, or SFTP server. I'm using an sftp server, so I simply input the address on the sftp server. `sftp.companyX.com/images`. This location will map to our **`Local Mount Path`** set inside your Lambda settings within the EFS configuration window (we'll look more at that in step 3).
  - **POSIX User**

    - `User ID:` `1054` | Locate your `/etc/passwd/` file and verify this to be true for your server hosting the EFS drive. I think `1054` is the default setting for *amazon linux* but if you're running a different OS on your EFS host, you should verify this value.
    - `Group ID:` `1054` (see last line)
  - **Root directory creation permissions**

    - `Owner User ID:` `1054` (see last line)
    - `Owner Group ID:` `1054` (see last line)
    - `POSIX permissions to apply to the root directory path`: `777` | understand these permissions translate to your `iamRoleStatements.Action` values; if they're different this `777` should be set appropriately.

**3. Lambdas addition of the EFS**

- `EFS File System:` (choose from dropdown selection)
- `Local Mount Path:`  | **SUPER IMPORTANT** e.g. `/mnt/my-efs`. This part is very non-intuitive IMO. This location, whatever you want it to be, will map to the `Root directory path` (step 2.4 above) you configured when you build your access point. Meaning, if you download an s3 file called `img.jpg` to `/mnt/my-efs/.` it will put that file into `sftp.company.com/images/img.jpg`.

**4. Downloading items into the EFS drive**

- Obviously, this can be done many ways. Your original code looked perfectly fine. I've simply extended it to extract the file location from an S3 event object as an example. If it's not obvious, the S3 event is triggered whenever the S3 bucket get's a new upload (a new object added to the bucket).

```py
class DownloadService:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.s3 = kwargs.get('s3_service')

    def download_files_to_efs(self, event):
        """
        Locates the S3 file name (i.e. S3 object "key" value) the initiated the Lambda call, then downloads the file
        into the locally attached EFS drive at the target location.
        :param: event | S3 event record
        :return: dict
        """
        key = event \
            .get('Records')[0] \
            .get('s3') \
            .get('object') \
            .get('key')  # 'some-bucket/some-folder/img.jpg'
        efs_loci = f"/mnt/my-efs/images/{key.split('/')[-1]}" # '/mnt/my-efs/images/img.jpg'
        result = self.s3.download('some-bucket', key, efs_loci)
        if result:
            print('Download Success...')
        else:
            print('Ask Stack Overflow :/')
        return {'status_code': 200}
```

**5. Verifying Your Files are in EFS**

- To verify the download works, you can just print the files from your EFS location from within your Lambda then check you built-in CloudWatch logs to see the results are as expected.

```py
import os

class DownloadService:
    #...constructor stuff

    @staticmethod
    def get_files_from_path(file_path):
        """
        Returns the files found at the file_path
        :param file_path: string
        :return list:
        """
        # NOTE: file_path = '/my-efs/

        found_files = []
        for _, _, f in os.walk(file_path):
            found_files.append(f)
        if found_files:
            print('efs files: ', found_files)
            return found_files
```

Special attention here! Notice i didn't read from `/mnt/my-efs/` i read from `/my-efs`, this is because the EFS `/` directory maps to the `/mnt` directory in the Lambda environment.

**Finished**

NOTE: If i've left something out feel free to comment and i'll add that as well if i can. Unfortunately i can't share the repo as it's a work related project (protected).

Comment: Thanks for this helpful solution you posted! Did you ever get the error `Function "myFunc": when using fileSystemConfig, ensure that function has vpc configured on function or provider level` when trying to deploy this? I've followed your example and have defined the VPC globally in the serverless.yml file, but still get this error.

Comment: @claudiadast If you're sure you have assigned your lambda to a VPC, then the next place to check is that your EFS is assigned to the same VPC. If all of that looks good, check your security groups, and internet gateway.

Comment: turns out I had a typo in my template of all things. Also, in your case, did you connect the Lambda function to a StepFunctions state machine or no?

Comment: @claudiadast i did not use a step function. Just an S3 trigger.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of @Tobiah answer. I got this answer from aws :

To access S3 service from a Lambda function we need either internet access or a S3 VPC endpoint.

Now, inorder to give lambda function internet access from inside of VPC, we would need to route traffic through a NAT gateway or NAT Instance. Placing lambda inside Public Subnet of VPC will not give internet access to lambda. [1]
You can attach private subnet(s) to lambda function which has a default route to the NAT gateway or NAT Instance which is launched inside the public subnet of VPC. Please refer to this document [2] for step by step guide. Kindly note that using NAT gateway will incur additional charges. [3]
Alternatively to use S3 VPC endpoint to connect lambda to S3. Please refer this document [4] for step by step guide.
Also, for encrypting files in EFS refer this document[5].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

[3] https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/encryption.html